# Authentication method return None in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

Hello I made a simple  registration and login page in django .when want to do login, authentication method inside the view of login return none.
my authentcate app
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email,
            password=password,

        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    # date_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

admin.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from .models import MyUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email',)
    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),

        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

# Now register the new UserAdmin...
admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)


**login app**

models.py



    from __future__ import unicode_literals
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
from django.core.validators import MaxLengthValidator
from django.db.models import Max
from authenticationUser.models import MyUser
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser,
#                                         PermissionsMixin,
#                                         UserManager)
# # Create your models here.

class Consultants(models.Model):
    # user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_name= models.OneToOneField(MyUser)
    consul_id=models.IntegerField(default=0,primary_key=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    # email=models.EmailField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    # password=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    consul_pic=models.ImageField(upload_to="/homeDocuments/pro//Registration/consul_pic",blank=True,null=True)
    mobile_no=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    country=models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(11)],blank=True,null=True)
    state=models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(11)],blank=True,null=True)
    city=models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(11)],blank=True,null=True)
    experience=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)
    skills=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    education=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    linkedin_id=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    cteated_on=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True,null=True)
    last_upadted_on=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True,null=True)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True,null=True)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # objects = UserManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name or u''


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # print "consul id",consul_id
        consul_id=int(self.consul_id)
        if consul_id==0:
            queryset=Consultants.objects.all()
            temp_id=queryset.aggregate(Max('consul_id'))
            print "second print",temp_id
            temp_id=temp_id.get('consul_id__max')
            print "third print",temp_id


            consul_id=""
            if not temp_id:
                consul_id="1"

            else:
                # int_consul= int(consul_id)
                consul_id=int(temp_id)+1
            self.consul_id=consul_id
        super(Consultants, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def login_user(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print type(username)
        # print "username",username
        try:
            print "username=========>",username
            print "password========>",password
            # user = Consultants.objects.get(Q(username= username) & Q(password= password))
            # obj=Consultants.objects.filter()
            # json = {"first_name":user.first_name,"email":user.email}
            # def form_valid(self, form):
            user=authenticate(email=username,password=password)
        # user = authenticate(Q(username= username) , Q(password= password))
        # user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            print 'chala',user
            if user.is_active:
                # user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
                # a=
                print 'user',user
                login(request, user)

                # a= request.user.username
                # print "abbabbaba",a

                return render(request, 'success.html', json)
                # return HttpResponse("welcome......you are succesfuly log in")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your  account is disabled.")
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("INvalid User")


    else:
         return render_to_response('login.html', context)
```

when i try to login and sed password and email id.It gets both field data but authenticate method return None.
For this i write  `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'register.Consultants'`  in my setting file, then another error showing   `AttributeError: type object 'Consultants' has no attribute 'REQUIRED_FIELDS'`

How can i get logged in by authenticate method.Why it is not working
Please help me in this

Comment: Did you try adding REQUIRED_FIELDS to that model?

Comment: if my authentication will complete by adding required files then i will surely want to add required files

Comment: i want to authenticate my user

Comment: Uncomment `REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']` in your model. You need to have that field.

Answer (score 0):

you have your custom user model named `MyUser` however in your configuration you reference totally different `register.Consultants` - use `MyUser` model.

From what can I see, every user will be a Consultant, so why not to simplify all of your code and create one model class `Consultants` which will handle user and profile information:

```
class Consultant(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    consul_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to="/homeDocuments/pro//Registration/consul_pic", blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(11)], blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(11)], blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(11)], blank=True, null=True)
    experience = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    skills = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    linkedin_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

few, off-topic comments:

- is_staff flag is used by default admin implementation to limit access of non-superuser users to the admin; this is important if you would like to use *any* permission e.g. some users will not be able to edit other user data, or you want to remove right to delete some records for some of them, with only superuser flag - every user can do everything
- why you had decided to manage primary key manually? this is not only bad code, but it may generate errors when there will be many requests at the same time
- by convention, class names should be singular - one record is one Consultant
- if you use one-to-one - use it as your primary key - just to simplify code and have better understanding what is there
- if you reference other model as foreign key or one-to-one - you still reference whole model not it's propery, so `user_name = models.OneToOneField(MyUser)` should be `user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser)`, so then it will be clear when you will access `consultant_x.user.name`
- I do not know why you had put country, state and city as integer fields... plus MaxLengthValidator will not work with integers integers do not have len() method
- for the date-time fields, there are `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` flags - much better than `default`