# why Authenticate returns None in django

Tags: python, django

i am trying to authenticate my custom user

```
def login_user(request):
    print "hi"
    context = RequestContext(request)
    email = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
        # print type(username)
        # print "username",username
    try:
        print "email-->",email, "password", password
        user=authenticate(username=email,password=password)

        print 'user-->',user
        if user.is_active:
            json = {"email":email} 
            return render(request, 'success.html', json)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Your  account is disabled.")
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("INvalid User")
```

when i hit this code it always give me user==None.
my authenticate method return None.Why this is happening

Comment: `user=authenticate(username=email,password=password)` maybe?

Comment: as @KlausD. says, you are trying to authenticate "email" and "password" as strings instead of their variables

Comment: are you sure you have added all the necessary settings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663083/django-authenticate-returns-none Did you try this?

Comment: @ mukund i have add model backend

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860961/                          this is my full code

Comment: If you've already asked the question before then you should update it with new information, not reask it.

Comment: @Sayse can u provide me answer

Comment: Of the 9 of the related questions on the right, all with the same name, there are 9 answers provided.

Answer (score 2):

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

it returns none because username with the specified EMAIL you given is not matching, the authenticate method authenticates by username not by email to use email as username specify as above and also use User.DoesNotExist for for exception.

Comment: perhaps u did not see my code.i used this in my code   ` is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']
`

Comment: have you registered your authentication backend in settings?

Answer (score 1):

```
user=authenticate(username="email",password="password")
```

If you give the value in quotes, it will take raw value. Remove quotes and try as follows to get the value of variable to be substituted.

```
user=authenticate(username=email,password=password)
```

Comment: i want to give hard code user so i used quotes.

Comment: Have you tried login with same credentials to your site? you will get None if your credentials are wrong or the user doesnt exist also.

Comment: here is my full code                                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860961/

Comment: >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> users = User.objects.get(username='admin')
>>> users
<User: admin>

Execute the above in your django shell and post the output please

Comment: DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.

Comment: >>> users = User.objects.get(username='amrita@gmail.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 334, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
>>>

Answer (score 1):

pass variables instead of their names as strings

```
user=authenticate(username=email, password=password)
```

instead of

```
user=authenticate(username="email", password="password")
```

[here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L12-L24) you see why it returns `None`

Comment: i also passed variables instead of their names.but nothing helped me

Comment: @CPVerma then your credentials are wrong. did you check your db? can you make sure that your db contains the exact same data you are giving to authenticate?

Comment: @ doniyor i checked my credentials  1000 times.

Comment: here is my full code                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860961/